# svn error: E204899 by check out using ECLIPSE

Tags: eclipse, svn

I have a problem with `svn` using in `ECLIPSE`. I am not able to check out and get the following error:

```
svn: E204899: Unable to make directories
```

I checked my network and it works fine. The other point which I tried was, to remove the whole folder using by ECLIPSE and started it from beginning. It did not help! I tried with different files it dose not make any different.
take into note that I am working under Windows and not Linux.
I checked the log file I found the following:

```
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the error detail its permission issue for your checkout directory.You have to checkout in directory where read and write permission are available so while checkout sub directories can be created so try to check after giving read/write permission to your directory with administrative user account.

Comment: Thanks for your hint I checked it and I have read/write permission in this folder! I added just before the error which I see in the log file according to Java probably it can help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem :). I do not know whether it is the general approach but I did the following :
the error message which I saw was not complete I checked the log file written in `.metadata`  and found the both error in java which I put at the end of my post above.

Go to Help -> check for updates -> updated the svn java kit.

Then I went to Window -> preference -> team -> SVN-> SVN Connector 
and chose the native javaHL.1.8.14 as the connector

Answer (score 0):

I had this error too in Jenkins. But only using the svn plugin in eclipse gave me the real error. The problem was a filename with some invalid characters